# Why does my pumpkin patch have only male blossoms?

Tags: vegetables, pumpkins

I have a pumpkin patch in Illinois with 30 plants. They're all in bloom now but are only sprouting male blossoms. How do I get them to give me female blossoms? I'm worried I won't have a single pumpkin from this patch.

Answer (score 5):

How long have they been in bloom? Usually the first flush of blossoms are all male - the female blossoms will show up later - in my experience, a week or so after you first see blooms. They grow fairly fast, so I'm betting you'll have squash before it frosts.

Comment: They've been bloom for a couple days.

Comment: yup you may not get a female flower for a couple of weeks... that is normal.